# python spatial map of averages using h5pyd

Tags: python

I have an h5 dataset read in using h5pyd and hsds that is very large and contains a variable (say temperature) that varies in both space (lat and long) and time. What is the most efficient method of taking the average over the time series at each point? Is there a vectorised method for this, currently I'm looping through the coordinates which is very slow for such a large dataset.